# Об употреблении слова "и" в указаниях

Tags: семантика

Предположим на столике лежат туз, король, дама, валет и пистолет (например, 12-го калибра).

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза, короля и даму." означает указание "Возьми туза, даму и короля.",
- указание "Возьми пистолет, прицелься и выстрели." означает указание "Возьми пистолет, выстрели и прицелься."?

P.S. Ларf и прочие филологи, которые не видят разницы в семантике моих предложений, вправе не отвечать на сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: Ну конечно во втором случае есть разница в порядке действий(выстрели и прицелься - бессмысленно),  и вы это видите, зачем же спрашиваете? Раскройте тайну.

Answer (score 1):

"Возьми (три карты) туза, даму и короля".

Никого не заботит, как вы это будете делать. Можете брать по одной карте в любом порядке. Можно попробовать схватить все три  одной рукой, и если случайно уроните карту - тоже не беда, главное - результат. Действие закончено, карты у вас в руках, указание выполнено. Сочинительная связь и замыкающий союз И объединяют предметы в группу, по отношению к которой выполняется действие.

"Возьми пистолет, прицелься и выстрели".

Здесь три разных действия, выраженные однородным рядом сказуемых. Сочинительная бессоюзная связь и замыкающий союз И выражают последовательность действий, которая должна быть соблюдена.